# Modify an array of slices/references

Tags: rust, slice, borrow-checker

I am new to Rust, and I am having a hard time wrapping my head around some of the reference/borrow behavior.

Here is a snippet which does not compile. I am attempting to create an array of `u64` "slices", whose values I want to modify, and then access later:

```
fn main() {
    // Initialize an array of "slices" with dummy data
    let mut refs: [&[u64]; 4] = [&[0; 2]; 4];

    // Write some computed values to the array
    for i in 0..refs.len() {
        // ...
        // some computation to get `x` and `y`
        // ...
        let data: [u64; 2] = [x as u64, y as u64];
        let data_ref: &[u64] = &data;
        refs[i] = data_ref;
    }

    // Read the computed values from the array
    println!("{}", refs[3][0]);
}
```

The compiler returns:

```
error[E0597]: `data` does not live long enough
  --> src\main.rs:8:32
   |
7  |         let data: [u64; 2] = [x as u64, y as u64];
   |             ---- binding `data` declared here
8  |         let data_ref: &[u64] = &data;
   |                                ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
9  |         refs[i] = data_ref;
10 |     }
   |     - `data` dropped here while still borrowed
...
13 |     println!("{}", refs[3][0]);
   |                    ------- borrow later used here
```

While I understand that `data` is scoped to live within the `for` loop, and that it will no longer exist outside of the `for` loop (so setting `refs[i]` to reference `data` should result in a compiler error since `refs` outlives `data`), I am unsure of an alternative way to correctly set values of `refs`.

What is the appropriate ("rusty") way to declare, initialize, then read "slice" values from an array like this?

Comment: Why are they slices? If you need a variable-length, owned slice, there's `Vec`. If you need a constant-length, owned slice, there's arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is slices reference data that lives "somewhere else". They also can't really outlive the data they reference.

If you define

```
let data: [u64; 2] = [x as u64, y as u64];
```

in your loop then `data` dies with each iteration. Therefore

you can't have

```
let data_ref: &[u64] = &data;
refs[i] = data_ref;
```

as, when the loop finishes, it would make `refs` contain a reference to a piece of data that doesn't exist anymore (`data`).

In your example you can replace slices with 2-element arrays, like so:

```
fn main() {
    let mut arrays = [[0; 2]; 4];

    // Write some computed values to the array
    for i in 0..arrays.len() {
        // ...
        // some computation to get `x` and `y`
        // ...
        let x = 1;
        let y = 2;
        arrays[i] = [x, y];
    }

    // Read the computed values from the array
    println!("{}", arrays[3][0]);
}
```

the the code prints `1`.

If you truly need an array of slices (for example when you get `refs` from the outside) I think you likely need copy the data into the slices, like so:

(Edit: added the explicit `[&mut [u64]; 4]` type after drewtato's note)

```rust
fn main() {
    // Initialize an array of "slices" with dummy data
    // The array doesn't need to be mutable (we don't modify it)
    // The slices have to be mutable (we modify them)
    let refs: [&mut [u64]; 4] = [&mut [0; 2], &mut [0; 2], &mut [0; 2], &mut [0; 2]];

    // Write some computed values to the array
    for i in 0..refs.len() {
        // ...
        // some computation to get `x` and `y`
        // ...
        let x = 1;
        let y = 2;
        refs[i].copy_from_slice(&[x, y]);
    }

    // Read the computed values from the array
    println!("{}", refs[3][0]);
}
```

(I have this ugly `[&mut [0; 2], &mut [0; 2], &mut [0; 2], &mut [0; 2]]` form in there because `[&mut [0; 2]; 4]` won't work – mutable array references aren't `Copy` so it's not so easy to initialize `refs` that way).

See [`copy_from_slice` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the help! That clears things up. The fact that mutable slices don't implement the `Copy` trait was the main limitation I didn't know I was facing.

Comment: Your last example doesn't make an array of slices, it's actually `[&mut [u64; 2]; 4]` (array of references to arrays). However, this is pretty inconsequential because if you try to use it in a way that requires it to be a slice (like assigning a slice to one of the elements) then type inference will turn it into `[&mut [u64]; 4]`. You can also make it an array of slices by specifying the type explicitly.

Comment: You're right @drewtato, of course – I added the explicit type, thank you.

@archer: In general if you mean for `refs` to own the data I'd suggest to just have arrays or `Vec`s there, not references to temporary data (which `&[0; 2]` and `&mut [0; 2]` are)